# Windows Server 2008 network trouble

Tags: windows, networking, winpe

Yesterday I was installing a new IP on my windows server 2008 and suddenly it just crashed. My server provider put the server in rescue mode with WinPE OS and the only thing I have access to is the file-system through filezilla. Windows Server 2008 starts, it just doesn't have a connection to the internet so I can't connect through RDP or anything.
I tried resetting everything through CMD in WinPE (ipconfig, netsh and such) but it seems to only apply to WinPE, which is on X:\ drive and not windows server 2008 which is on C:.
I'd rather not do a full system restore since the setup takes weeks worth of time that I haven't got right now.  I also tried putting a batch script in the registry that automatically runs when windows starts up but the registry only applies to WinPE.

Do you have any tips on how I can restore the network settings through the file system? I can't access windows while it's running, and according to my host it is running (but has no network connection at all). My host won't manually access the server to reset it either.

Answer (score 1):

1. In WinPE, open a command prompt (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>) and start the Registry Editor (`regedit.exe`).
2. Click `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` then File, Load Hive. Locate the System registry hive on your faulty machine (e.g. `\Windows\System32\Config\SYSTEM`). You will be asked to create a friendly name for this node -- use `BANANA`.
3. Navigate the tree, down to SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services then start a search (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) for `DefaultGateway`. This search should complete with a hit in `{guid}\Parameters\Tcpip` with several registry values such as `DefaultGateway`, `EnableDHCP`, `IPAddress` and `SubnetMask`.
4. Double-click the various values and change them as needed.
5. Continue the steps above (using <kbd>F3</kbd> to repeat your search) until each hit is updated with the correct values. (There will only be a few more.)
6. Unload the hive by clicking the `BANANA` node, then File, Unload Hive.
7. Reboot.

Or you can simply throw together a batch file and run that at boot.

1. Instead of opening the SYSTEM hive above, open the SOFTWARE hive and drill down to `BANANA\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.
2. Create a new REG_SZ (String) value with the name `FixMe`. Set its data to `C:\FixMe.bat`.
3. Create a file on the C:\ named FixMe.bat and fill it with:

   `netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static [IP] [MASK] [GW] 1 >FixMe.log`

   Replace [IP] [MASK] and [GW] as appropriate (x.x.x.x notation).
4. Reboot.

Comment: This looks like a safer way to go, try this first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I did this but it didn't affect anything really. Do you know if you can use this method to run a batch file on windows startup? Using Winlogon with automatic login and then put a batch script that resets network settings in the startup folder?

Comment: Good idea, I added those steps to the answer above. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, I did as you wrote and restarted the server on C:\, and got this error: Server found in ?Windows startup repair? mode and it went back to WinPE again.. I checked the registry and everything was still there (FixMe, etc).

The only thing I did different was that I also added this to Winlogon so that it doesn't just stop at login screen: http://i.imgur.com/pR1qoZD.png

Comment: After 3 or so interrupted or unsuccessful restarts of Windows, it will enter startup repair mode. Try another reboot :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your host does things, but if you can access filesystem you can probably swap your registry files manually for an older version if you have some sort of way to access them.

If I remember correctly TCP/IP parameters are something like

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces
```

So you need to swap these out for an older version:

```
%windir%\system32\config\SYSTEM
%windir%\system32\config\SOFTWARE
%windir%\system32\config\SECURITY
%windir%\system32\config\SAM
%windir%\system32\config\Default
```

If you have shadowcopy or system restore or backup should be no problem.
It's a risky business tho, so backup your original files first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have never though of having backups of the registry, but do you think there is some default you could download from somewhere?

Comment: No, do not get registry files from another machine - you will mess yours up badly. If you have system restore turned on it made registry copies automatically. I think they are somewhere in system volume information folder. Some Windows versions had default registry files in c:\windows\repair, but I'm not sure if that is the case here.